# Angular controller function placement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, separation-of-concerns

So I have a `clearNotification` function I want to trigger when I click the '#upload' button. I set an ng-click on that button to trigger `notify()`.

What I'm wondering is if it's a violation of separation of concerns to put that `clearNotification` function within `notify()`. Is it better to add that as another ng-click on '#upload'? Or is this where directives come in?

Would love any input on this.

So far, this is what my code looks like:

HTML:

```
<button id="upload" ng-click="notify()">Upload</button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.clearNotification = function() {
  $scope.notification = '';
};

$scope.notify = function() {
  $scope.clearNotification();
  ...
};
```

Comment: Do you really need to define `clearNotification` in the scope? Do you use it somewhere like in `ngClick`? You maybe only need normal function definition `function clearNotification() {...}`.

Comment: yea that is what I will be doing if its better to keep it the way it is now.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with calling controller functions from other controller functions.

If the clearNotification function has some business logic, then add it to a service(and inject that service into your controller). Thats the correct way to seperate components.

Should this be a directive? Only if this is a re-usable component that can live alone.